# Wireless issue: Ubuntu 16.04 on HP Pavilion Laptop

Tags: wireless, hp

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Pavilion Laptop. However, the wifi won't connect unless I'm too close to the router! Upon reading on the issue, I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to generate a wireless-info.txt file containing the details needed to diagnose the issue. Here is the link to txt file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20909726/

I hope some expert can help me solve this problem given the info in the link above.

Comment: I would suggest changing your router to *NOT* use TKIP.